# ORACLE SQL Query Table using criteria from other table

Tags: sql, string, oracle

TABLEA contains the data, while TABLEB contains the search criteria

Here is a [SQL Fiddle with the data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a00b8/1)

1. **Tables**

   ```
   TABLEA
   visited_states_time
   AL= Alabama,2, AK=Alaska,5
   AR=Arkansas,6
   AZ=Arizona,10
   CA=California, 10,CT=Connecticut,20

   TABLEB
   CRITERIA
   AL
   HI
   CA
   CT
   AK
   ```
2. **Desired Result**

   ```
   visited_states ...................................     total_time_spent
   AL= Alabama, AK=Alaska ............................     7
   CA=California, CT=Connecticut...................        30
   ```

Comment: Normalize your data and the pain will go away.

Comment: The data in your sql fiddle does not match what you posted above.

Answer (score 1):

That's a terrible data model. also you didn't say the condition for `tableb`. if any state matches, or if all?

as we need to split the rows up (to sum()) and then recombine them you can use:

```
SQL> with v as (select rownum r,
  2                    ','||visited_states_time||',' visited_states_time,
  3                    length(
  4                      regexp_replace(visited_states_time, '[^,]', '')
  5                    )+1 fields
  6               from tablea)
  7  select trim(both ',' from visited_states_time) visited_states_time,
  8         sum(total_time_spent) total_time_spent
  9    from (select *
 10            from v
 11                 model
 12                 partition by (r)
 13                 dimension by (0 as f)
 14                 measures (visited_states_time, cast('' as varchar2(2)) state,
 15                           0 as total_time_spent, fields)
 16                 rules (
 17                   state[for f from 0 to fields[0]-1  increment 2]
 18                     = trim(
 19                        substr(visited_states_time[0],
 20                               instr(visited_states_time[0], ',', 1, cv(f)+1)+1,
 21                               instr(visited_states_time[0], '=', 1, (cv(f)/2)+1)
 22                               - instr(visited_states_time[0], ',', 1,  cv(f)+1)-1
 23                              )),
 24                   visited_states_time[any]= visited_states_time[0],
 25                   total_time_spent[any]
 26                      = substr(visited_states_time[0],
 27                               instr(visited_states_time[0], ',', 1, (cv(f)+2))+1,
 28                               instr(visited_states_time[0], ',', 1,  (cv(f)+3))
 29                               - instr(visited_states_time[0], ',', 1,  (cv(f)+2))-1
 30                             )
 31                 ))
 32   where state in (select criteria from tableb)
 33   group by visited_states_time;

VISITED_STATES_TIME                   TOTAL_TIME_SPENT
------------------------------------- ----------------
CA=California, 10,CT=Connecticut,20                 30
AL=Alabama,2, AK=Alaska,5                            7
```

but seriously, rewrite that data model to store them separately to start with.

Comment: Whack 'em with the MODEL clause!  That'll teach them to use a proper data structure!